# ffmpeg: How to convert quicktime (iPhone) video to mp4 format?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to convert quicktime (.mov) video file recorded by iphone, into mp4 format using ffmpeg in php.

I tried several commands but it did not work for me.

I tried following command that converted into .mp4 but just audio was there. No video was playing.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i input.mov out.mp4");
```

Any help in this case will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the ffmpeg output when you execute the command. Also post some more info about the file. Preferably a MediaInfo or ffprobe output.

Comment: Have you tried just renaming the .mov extension to .mp4 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to ffmpeg, but if you want the codecs to remain the same and the data wrapped in mp4 instead of mov, I believe the following will work:

```
 ffmpeg -i video.mov -c copy video.mp4
```

The command you posted may have worked just fine, but your computer is having trouble playing the video data. This is almost always a codec issue.

You can compare the data in the mov input with the mp4 output using ffprobe. Compare the output of the commands `ffprobe video.mov` and `ffprobe video.mp4`. If the above command works as expected, then the data should read the same under the codecs. Only the container related data should be different.

Answer (score 0):

MP4 file format is based on QuickTime file format. Usually, renaming the file suffix to `.mp4` just works.

The spec are here

- [ISO/IEC 14496-12:2015](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html)
- [QuickTime File Format(QTFF)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFPreface/qtffPreface.html)

Comment: That is false information. While ideas were taken from QuickTime, they are different formats and simply renaming a file doesn't convert it into a mp4 file. As it also says in the second link you posted.

Comment: Container structure is the same and often renaming can work. FFmpeg has the same demuxer for `mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2`. But QT allows lot more codecs than the official MP4 format, So a player coded as per the spec to vet streams will refuse to play a MP4 with e.g. PCM audio or just won't play the audio, just like ffmpeg won't create such a MP4. But nothing technical prevents PCM in MP4. Sony's cameras produce such MP4s. ----------- **TL;DR** difference between MP4 and MOV is administrative rather than technical. The viability of renaming MP4/MOV depends on the app the file is to be used in.

Comment: Renaming would work for VLC (anything would work for VLC) but not for players like QuickTime.